# Why do I get this failure and why is mysql set to false?

Tags: python, mysql, exception

I wanted to put these data into the database, but the insertion failed, probably because the statement was wrong.

python3.6

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pymysql

tup = ('222.72.166.235:53281', '上海', '高匿', 'HTTPS')
name = tup[0]
ip_list = tup[0].split(':')
ip = ip_list[0]
port = ip_list[1]
location = tup[1]
anonymity = tup[2]
protocol = tup[3]
#instr = "'{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', ".format(name, ip, port, location, anonymity, protocol)
db_test = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '123456', "test")
cursor = db_test.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO public_proxy(name, ip, port, location, anonymity, protocol) VALUES('%s', '%s',  '%s',  '%s',  '%s', '%s')" % (name, ip, port, location, anonymity, protocol)
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db_test.commit()
    print('数据插入成功...')  
except:
    db_test.rollback()
    print('错误')
db_test.close()
```

I hope result the 'print('数据插入成功...')'

```
错误
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

[enter image description here][1]

This is the database structure table.

```
mysql> desc public_proxy;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(25)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip          | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| port        | varchar(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location    | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| anonymity   | tinyint(3)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| protocol    | tinyint(3)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| source      | varchar(25)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| create_time | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: You are trying to put strings into tinyint columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always examine the exception when you catch it in an `except` block. It will give you clues about the nature of the exception, and a specific error message.

I tried testing your script, but I changed the exception handler to the following:

```
except Exception as e:
    db_test.rollback()
    print('错误')
    print("{0}: {1!r}".format(type(e).__name__, e.args))
```

I got this output:

```
错误
ProgrammingError: (1146, u"Table 'test.public_proxy' doesn't exist")
```

This is expected in my environment, because I didn't create the table before I ran this script.

In your case, there might be a different cause for the exception.

The point is that you must examine information in the exception, or else you cannot know the cause.

---

Re your comment:

The error indicates that you are trying to store a string into an integer column, and MySQL won't convert it.

You should use a numeric value.

Comment: ```
错误
InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '高匿' for column 'anonymity' at row 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally, there was a problem with the value I inserted, but now I have made a modification and it is successful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pymysql

tup = ('222.72.166.235:53281', '上海', '高匿', 'HTTPS')
name = tup[0]
ip_list = tup[0].split(':')
ip = ip_list[0]
port = ip_list[1]
location = tup[1]
anonymity = tup[2]
protocol = tup[3]
source = 'xici'

if anonymity == '透明':
    anonymity = 0
elif anonymity == '高匿':
    anonymity = 1
elif anonymity == '':
    anonymity =2
else:
    anonymity = 3

if protocol == 'HTTP':
    protocol = 0
elif protocol == 'HTTPS':
    protocol = 1
elif protocol == '':
    protocol = 2
else:
    protocol = 3
#instr = "'{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', ".format(name, ip, prot, location, anonymity, protocol)
db_test = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '123456', "test")
cursor = db_test.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO public_proxy(name, ip, port, location, anonymity, protocol, source) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (name, ip, port, location, anonymity, protocol, source)
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db_test.commit()
    print('数据插入成功...')  
except Exception as e:
    db_test.rollback()
    print('错误')
    print("{0}: {1!r}".format(type(e).__name__, e.args))

db_test.close()
```

result:

```
数据插入成功...
```

thx,my friend.